# Binding properties to POJO (@ConfigurationProperties style)

Tags: spring-boot

How do I bind properties to a POJO in Spring Boot?

- A POJO class is a 3rd party library class - I can't put @ConfigurationProperties there.
- There could be several instances of the same class, depedending of property name suffix.
- Registering it as a bean is not required. Most likely instances are created in runtime.
- Also features: validation, formatted parsing, relaxed names, collections, nested classes, prefix/suffix support, unknown properties ignoring.

I know some utility classes like DataBinder that could help, but probabaly there is a quicker way.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could just extend the 3rd party POJO and add `@ConfigurationProperties` to your own class like this:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myNamespace")
@Component
public class CustomProperties1 extends ThirdPartyProperties {

}
```

Then, you can configure all the properties of the 3rd party POJO with properties like `myNamespace.propertyName=value`.

However, I would be careful with that approach, since you give up control over the names of your configuration properties. When a field name changes in the 3rd party library, the configuration parameter will no longer be bound.

Comment: For that concern you can write a unit test to test the bindings. If field names in the POJO would change, you would also get compile errors then.